Applying background color to single cell based on php value
I am relatively new to php and cannot figure out why the background-color value is being applied to all cells rather than just the one. My "Admin Page" is able to save a value called 'color' in SESSION. I then use that value and echo it to select the appropriate color based on the button I selected [Red/red, Yellow/yellow, etc]. However when I select a color, it applies that same color to all cells within the 'Ref' column.
Admin page

Ref cells

<?php
            
$query = 'SELECT * FROM iriso_log_table ORDER BY log_id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rc = 0; //row count for column splitting
$i = 0;
$n = 0;
$color = $_SESSION['color'];

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($element = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $i++;
?>

        <!--Display-->
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
            <input type="hidden" name="log_id" value="<?php echo $element['log_id']; ?>">  
            <td><?php echo $element['carrier_name']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $element['pallet_count']; ?></td>            
            <td style="background-color: <?php echo $color ?>"><?php echo $element['ref']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $element['c_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $element['special_note']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $element['dom_inbond']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $element['arriv_date'] . " / " . $element['arriv_time']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $element['ship_date']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        
<?php   
    
    }   
}
?>

I am thinking it may have something to do with resetting the value back to white after I have finished using it but cannot seem to find the correct placement or command for this.
This is where I set my 'color' variable in SESSION
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'urgent'))
{
    $_SESSION['color'] = "red";
}

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hold'))
{
    $_SESSION['color'] = "yellow";
}

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'good'))
{
    $_SESSION['color'] = "green";
}

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clear'))
{
    $_SESSION['color'] = "white";
}


PLease dont post pictures of code! Its text, post it here as text

There's only one $color variable, it's used every time through the loop. If you want different colors on different rows, you need some conditional code.

What is the criteria for which cells should have the selected background color?

Where do you maintain/set $_SESSION['color'] Its not in this code

My apologies for posting my code as a picture, I have edited my post to share it as code. The cell color will be determined by what button I press. So for example when I press the red circle button on Admin Page, it is marked as urgent and thus the Ref cell should turn red. The issue is that when I mark Order 1 as urgent, it also colors Order 2 and Order 3 as urgent [i.e. red] as shown in Ref Cells picture
